# Folder upload over the network with Absolute path

Tags: java, html

In JAVA using Struts 1.3 ,Im uploading a single file from File browser from Form,End user will access my application URL and browse file from his local machine,and on my application server Database is here.Values get inserted into my DB while uploading single File.

But I dont know how to upload complete Folder from Local machine.

I think this is done by something called AbsolutePath.

Kindly help me soon.
Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Please add your code so far by using the "edit" link below your question. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) What have you tried so far?
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.